# How to extend conda base environment?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

I want to create conda environment, for using mainly jupyter lab.

I've tried:

```
conda create --name NLPConda anaconda
```

and also

```
conda create --name NLPConda --clone base
```

But receiving:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done
```

PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')

I've tried it several times, even tried to remove Anaconda from my computer and re-install it. This is my current version: `conda 4.5.11`

I also tried to create a virtual environment without cloning the base, but then jupyter-lab doesn't work.

My main use it to activate JupyterLab in a cloned conda environment. What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did two things to make it work:
1. Reinstall in the default provided location
2. Run the installation as an administrator

Comment: I am having the same problem. Launched powershell "as administrator" and tried to clone the base environment `(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda create --name nambu --clone base
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Source:      C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
Destination: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nambu
The following packages cannot be cloned out of the root environment:
 - defaults::conda-4.6.11-py37_0
 - defaults::conda-build-3.17.8-py37_0
 - defaults::conda-env-2.6.0-1
Packages: 258`   Env seems to be working though?